# How to train an SVM with opencv based on a set of images?

Tags: opencv, svm

I have a folder of positives and another of negatives images in JPG format, and I want to train an SVM based on that images, I've done the following but I receive an error:

```
Mat classes = new Mat();
Mat trainingData = new Mat();

Mat trainingImages = new Mat();
Mat trainingLabels = new Mat();

CvSVM clasificador;

for (File file : new File(path + "positives/").listFiles()) {
        Mat img = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
        img.reshape(1, 1);

        trainingImages.push_back(img);
        trainingLabels.push_back(Mat.ones(new Size(1, 1), CvType.CV_32FC1));
    }

    for (File file : new File(path + "negatives/").listFiles()) {
        Mat img = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
        img.reshape(1, 1);

        trainingImages.push_back(img);
        trainingLabels.push_back(Mat.zeros(new Size(1, 1), CvType.CV_32FC1));
    }

    trainingImages.copyTo(trainingData);
    trainingData.convertTo(trainingData, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    trainingLabels.copyTo(classes);

    CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
    params.set_kernel_type(CvSVM.LINEAR);

    clasificador = new CvSVM(trainingData, classes, new Mat(), new Mat(), params);
```

When I try to run that I obtain:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix) in cvCheckTrainData, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 857
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:857: error: (-5) train data must be floating-point matrix in function cvCheckTrainData
]
    at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.CvSVM_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.<init>(CvSVM.java:80)
```

I can't manage to train the SVM, any idea? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to classify plates based on segmets I already obtained, my code is based on this example: https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter5_NumberPlateRecognition/trainSVM.cpp

Comment: Did You try using CV_64F? And did You, just to be absolutely sure, check what is the type of `trainingData` just before it is passed into CvSVM?

Comment: thanks @morynicz, 'CvType.typeToString(trainingData.type())' would return "CV_32FC3".. Also tried converting to CV_64F with the same error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you know what you are doing by reshaping an image and using it to train SVM, the most probable cause of this is that your

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

fails to actually read an image, generating a matrix `img` with null `data` property, which will eventually trigger the following in the OpenCV code:

```
// check parameter types and sizes
if( !CV_IS_MAT(train_data) || CV_MAT_TYPE(train_data->type) != CV_32FC1 )
    CV_ERROR( CV_StsBadArg, "train data must be floating-point matrix" );
```

Basically `train_data` fails the first condition (being a valid matrix) rather than failing the second condition (being of type CV_32FC1).

In addition, even though reshape works on the `*this` object, it acts like a filter and its effect is not permanent. If it's used in a single statement without immediately being used or assigned to another variable it will be useless. Change the following lines in your code:

```
img.reshape(1, 1);
trainingImages.push_back(img);
```

to:

```
trainingImages.push_back(img.reshape(1, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says, You need to change type of Your matrix, from integer type, probably CV_8U, to floating point one, CV_32F or CV_64F. To do it You can use [`cv::Mat::convertTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto). [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) is a bit about depths and types of matrices.

Comment: actually I do: 'trainingData.convertTo(trainingData, CvType.CV_32FC1);' and my 'classes' is populated with [1] CV_32FC1 ones matrix

Comment: Oops. Sorry, didn't see that.