# Training SVM bad argument error

Tags: java, opencv, svm

I followed the code in [How to train an SVM with opencv based on a set of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876960/how-to-train-an-svm-with-opencv-based-on-a-set-of-images) and I get the following exception

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix) in cvCheckTrainData, file ......\src\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 857
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: ......\src\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:857: error: (-5) train data must be floating-point matrix in function cvCheckTrainData
]

I followed the steps as mentioned in the comment. But still in vain.

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat classes = new Mat();
        Mat trainingData = new Mat();
        Mat trainingImages = new Mat();
        Mat trainingLabels = new Mat();
        CvSVM clasificador;
        String path="C:\\java workspace\\ora\\images\\Color_Happy_jpg";
        for (File file : new File(path).listFiles()) {
            Mat img=new Mat();   
            Mat con = Highgui.imread(path+"\\"+file.getName());
            con.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32F,1.0/255.0);

                img.reshape(1, 1);


                trainingImages.push_back(img);
               trainingLabels.push_back(Mat.ones(new Size(1, 1), CvType.CV_32F));
            }
        System.out.println("divide");
        path="C:\\java workspace\\ora\\images\\Color_Sad_jpg";
            for (File file : new File(path).listFiles()) {
                Mat img=new Mat();
                 Mat m=new Mat(new Size(640,480),CvType.CV_32FC3);
                Mat con = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());

                con.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32F,1.0/255.0);
                img.reshape(1, 1);
                trainingImages.push_back(img);
                System.out.println((CvType.typeToString(img.type())));
                trainingLabels.push_back(Mat.zeros(new Size(1, 1), CvType.CV_32F));
              }

            trainingLabels.copyTo(classes);
            CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
            params.set_kernel_type(CvSVM.LINEAR);

            System.out.println(CvType.typeToString(trainingImages.type()));
                        CvSVM svm=new CvSVM();
            System.out.println(svm.get_support_vector_count());
            boolean b=svm.train(trainingImages, classes);

            System.out.print(b);

 }
```

}

Comment: Clearly your training data is _not_ a floating-point matrix.

Comment: I converted to the type CV_32F. It still shows the same exception

Comment: Some code would be helpful to someone who might be able to help.

Comment: your train images should be grayscale, not 3channel (and they are far too large) also trainlabels should be a n-rows, 1 col float mat